# Nested Contextual Action Bars

Tags: android, webview, selection, contextual-action-bar

I am creating custom contextual action bars (CAB) within a custom `WebView`.

My requirements are such that selecting a particular option from the first CAB will open a second CAB. This is the end goal:

[image: When the user enters selection mode, this CAB appears.]
[image: When they tap the highlighter, this second CAB appears.]

I have made this happen, but the selection is not working correctly. I know it looks correct, but if the user taps any of the other three icons, this is the result:

[image: Tap other icons.]
[image: Selection hangs around when it isn't wanted.]

**If the user touches the selection after pressing any of the four initial icons, the app crashes due to a null pointer exception.**

When the user touches the lingering selection after selecting an action, the app tries to access the `ActionMode` (let's call it `firstActionMode`) that created the CAB with the icons in order to invalidate/refresh it. However, `firstActionMode` is destroyed when the CAB with the colors is created, (call that `secondActionMode`) causing a null pointer exception.

---

In order to clear away the selection, I have found that calling `clearFocus()` within `onDestroyActionMode(firstActionMode)` method does the job just fine.

```
private class CustomActionModeCallback extends ActionMode.Callback {
    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        clearFocus();
    }
}
```

However, when this is implemented, the selection does not persist when `secondActionMode` creates its CAB:

[image: Same as before, but...]
[image: The selection disappears when any icon is clicked.]

Choosing a color from this point actually produces the desired functionality. However, while this "works," it (most unfortunately) does not meet my requirements. I need the selection to remain visible **and functional** when the CAB created by `secondActionMode` is shown.

---

Here is the code for my custom class (`WebView`) and its nested `ActionMode`s

```
public class CustomWebView extends WebView {

    private ActionMode.Callback mActionModeCallback;

    @Override
    public ActionMode startActionMode(Callback callback) {
        ViewParent parent = getParent();
        if (parent == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (callback instanceof HighlightActionModeCallback) {
            mActionModeCallback = callback;
        } else {
            mActionModeCallback = new CustomActionModeCallback();
        }       
        return parent.startActionModeForChild(this, mActionModeCallback);
    }

    private class CustomActionModeCallback implements ActionMode.Callback {
        // Called when the action mode is created; startActionMode() was called
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            // Inflate a menu resource providing context menu items
            MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.first_menu, menu);
            return true;
        }

        // Called each time the action mode is shown.
        // Always called after onCreateActionMode, but
        // may be called multiple times if the mode is invalidated.
        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            // This method is called when the handlebars are moved.
            return false; // Return false if nothing is done
        }

        // Called when the user selects a contextual menu item
        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.copy:
                // Do stuff
                break;
            case R.id.bookmark:
                // Do stuff
                break;

            case R.id.highlight:
                startActionMode(new HighlightActionModeCallback());
                break;

            case R.id.note:
                // Do stuff
                break;
            default:
                return false;
            }

            mode.finish(); // Action picked, so close the CAB
            return true;
        }

        // Called when the user exits the action mode
        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            clearFocus(); // This is commented in the first four screens.
        }
    }

    private class HighlightActionModeCallback implements ActionMode.Callback {

        // Called when the action mode is created; startActionMode() was called
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            // Inflate a menu resource providing context menu items
            MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.highlight_colors, menu);
            return true;
        }

        // Called each time the action mode is shown.
        // Always called after onCreateActionMode, but
        // may be called multiple times if the mode is invalidated.
        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            // This method is called when the handlebars are moved.
            return false; // Return false if nothing is done
        }

        // Called when the user selects a contextual menu item
        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            mode.finish(); // Action picked, so close the CAB
            return true;
        }

        // Called when the user exits the action mode
        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            // Remove the selection highlight and handles.
            clearFocus();
        }
    }

}
```

---

How can this be fixed? Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now solved this problem; I was over-thinking it. The solution lies not in an `ActionMode`, but within the menu.

Instead of starting an entirely new `ActionMode` for the color menu, **change the icon menu** if the highlighter is selected. Save a reference to the `Menu` parameter in `onCreateActionMode` and set a flag of some sort; I'm using a boolean.

```
private class CustomActionModeCallback implements ActionMode.Callback {

    private boolean highlighterClicked = false;
    private Menu mMenu;

    // Called when the action mode is created; startActionMode() was called
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        mMenu = menu;
        // Inflate a menu resource providing context menu items
        MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.first_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    // Called each time the action mode is shown.
    // Always called after onCreateActionMode, but
    // may be called multiple times if the mode is invalidated.
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        // This method is called when the handlebars are moved.
        MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
        if (highlighterClicked) {
            menu.clear(); // Remove the four icons
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.highlight_colors, menu); // Show the colors
            return true; // This time we did stuff, so return true
        }
        return false; // Return false if nothing is done
    }

    // Called when the user selects a contextual menu item
    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {

        highlighterClicked = false;
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.copy:
            // Do stuff
            break;
        case R.id.bookmark:
            // Do stuff
            break;

        case R.id.highlight:
            highlighterClicked = true;
            onPrepareActionMode(mode, mMenu);
            return true;

        case R.id.note:
            // Do stuff
            break;
        default:
            // Any of the colors were picked
            return true;
        }

        mode.finish(); // Action picked, so close the CAB
        return true;
    }

    // Called when the user exits the action mode
    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        clearFocus();
    }
}
```

The selection highlight and handles stay active and functional, and the color options work as intended.

It is safe to delete the second `ActionModeCallback` class; it is worthless. Again, way over-thought. :P