# Contextual Action Bar in Webview text Selection

Tags: android, menu, webview, contextual-action-bar

I found a lot of question about this problem, but I can't fix it. I am creating custom contextual action bars (CAB) within `WebView` i followed this [Tutorial](http://java.dzone.com/articles/contextual-action-bar-cab)

My problem is CAB working fine in `setOnLongClickListener` but i cant able to select the text.

I referred these links:

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23096993/nested-contextual-action-bars), [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15370047/overriding-the-default-contextual-action-bar-for-text-selectionin-webview-in-a)

**Edit :**

```
    mywebview.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
             mActionMode = MainActivity.this.startActionMode(new ActionBarCallBack());
             return true;
        }
    });
```

Implement the ActionMode.Callback interface:

```
    class ActionBarCallBack implements ActionMode.Callback {

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contextual_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

}
```

I Tried like this :

```
     @Override
     public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
     {
           super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
           mActionMode = Contents.this.startActionMode(new ActionBarCallBack());
     }
```

Help me where i am wrong. Thank in advanced

Comment: Should your onLongClick(View v) method return true if the callback is consuming the long click?

Comment: @gavlaaaaaaaa but i cant able to select the text..